# How to get data from Wamp server to my Android Cell Phone?

Tags: android, wamp

I have made an app using Android Studio, and I managed to retrieve data from WAMP in my emulator (using JSON parsing), but when I run the same app on my current physical device, the data does not appear even when I connect my laptop and my cell phone with USB, and also I've tried using the WiFi Hotspot from my cell phone.

Comment: try to replace the `localhost` to the ip address of your pc

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez if the op was using localhost as server address, the emulator would not work either.

Comment: try your current ip address or in emulator try 10.0.0.2

Comment: it works on my emulator, but no my mobile

Comment: Check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/a/38100156/2310830 it is what I use

Comment: Make sure that your server PC and your phone shares the same wifi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Answer (score -1):

> data does not appear even when I connect my laptop and my cell phone with USB

WAMP is a web server, it does not transfer data over USB

> I managed to retrieve data from Wamp in my emulator

That's good. You probably used an IP address of `10.0.2.2` to connect.

You can't use that address outside of the emulator on a physical device, though. You have to use the LAN IP address of the computer running WAMP. And you additionally need to check that WAMP is externally accesible by other devices in the network. (I'm not sure if that is the default configuration, or not).