# Making wamp server online for all mobile devices

Tags: wampserver

I have created an android application for simple login using wampserver. But it only works on my laptop. I need it to work on all mobile devices. How can i do that? please give me some step by step procedure. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43018881/2310830

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving a new inbound rule through your firewall? This was the case for my project. All I did was register Port 3306 for the MySQL database and it worked. We'll also need more information on your project because your post doesn't have enough information on your dilemma. You can also try USB tethering on your device.