# How can i access to my PHP application on my smartphone using a DNS local adress

Tags: php, wampserver, httpd.conf

I have a PHP application running on wamp3. I have being able to enable people  of my local network getting access to the application while typing 192.168.2.22/myapps. I'm looking how to make  them instead type www.myapps.dev for to get access to the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: This is one solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016713/wampserver-access-server-from-mobile-phone/43018881#43018881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

French speaking to... but answer will be in English ;)

So, in order to access a server, you need its IP.

**First way to access**

Like you already do, directly through the IP

**Common way to access**

The user is calling a DNS name which is translated by an IP using a DNS server. Using this technique will imply technical abilities in server management and networking.

**Developer way**

The user configures the specified host on his terminal. On Linux and Android, you can update /etc/hosts file in order to add IP / DNS correlations. You may find "Hosts editor" application in Play Store.

Note that this technique won't be available for iOS users.