# POST JSON without Internet with Genymotion

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, genymotion

I have local database and Android app in `Genymotion`. I want to send POST JSON without internet. Both sides of code is ok on USB Device and database with WIFI connection.  My database is written on ASP.Net web api 2 with azure functions.I tried to use different URL's

`http://198.168.67.2:7071/api/LogIn`

`http://10.0.3.2:7071/api/LogIn`

`http://10.0.3.15:7071/api/LogIn`

and nothing happened.
So, my question is: Can I send POST without internet using Genymotion and if yes how can I do this.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll need to connect the both desktop and your Android device (*such as emulator or a real device*) to a network which has a router.

Router will do the rest and it does not matter if it has internet connection or not.

So the solution will be that connecting both Desktop and the Android device to a local network which they can find the eachother.

Remember to add the Internet permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/4409113) for more information.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44353006/connect-an-android-app-to-localhost-without-internet-connection).

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016713/wampserver-access-server-from-mobile-phone/43018881#43018881) too.