# Can't access virtual host except localhost homepage in mobile - WAMP SERVER

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, wampserver

I am trying to access my web app from my phone connected via same router but I am being able to only access the localhost home page but when I click on the respective virtualhost, I am not being able to access the page.

I have setup my virtual host through the interface provide in wamp server.

**Wamp Server Version:** 3.0.6

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Require local
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName transmit
    DocumentRoot "d:/wamp64/www/transmit_renewed"
    <Directory  "d:/wamp64/www/transmit_renewed/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        #Require local
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you use an OS on your phone where you can edit the hosts file, or do you have some DNS resolution on your router? Your phone need a way to map the server name with the IP address of your server

Comment: @rypskar I didn't make any changes to my router except for configuring it to use the internet. And since I use a windows Lumia phone hence I won't be able to edit the hosts file on it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016713/wampserver-access-server-from-mobile-phone/43018881#43018881 for one method

Comment: @RiggsFolly, it didn't work. Under virtual host option in wamp server I get Duplicate_ServerName and VirtualHost_PortValue both with a yellow warning icon

Comment: @RiggsFolly Alright, despite the warning errors in wamp under **Your VirtualHosts**, using the address style as mentioned in the linked answer the page opens up from android's chrome browser but when I try to open it from my windows phone it straightaway takes me to the windows store. Any ideas/ fixes?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I replaced the **Require local** to **Require all granted** for the second virtual host created with port 8000 and it worked. Is it correctly done?

Comment: I think so, but I cannot see it so thats a guess

Comment: Shall I show you all the changes I made?