# WAMP Virtual Host Allow External Device

Tags: wamp, virtualhost

I am trying to use Ionic’s  Devapp to test some functionality on my phone.  I think that WAMP is not allowing the requests to make it through my virtual server.  I am using WAMP 3.1.3 with Apache 2.4 and I think I have it configured correctly, but requests are still not being received.  I am using windows 10 and have tried to take down my firewall and allow access through my firewall, but I still have not achieved the results and looking for I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for me to listen to the specific port provided by the ionic server and that’s used by Devapp with wamp.  Does it make a difference that it's a phone? Thanks for your help.

hostd.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:8001
Listen [::0]:8001
```

Httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.1.2.3:80>
    ServerName sam
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/x/public "
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/x/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:8001>
    ServerName example.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/x/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/x/public">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of a `Require ip` does not use the `x`, `x.y` part

Just use

```
Require ip 192.168
```

and that means any ip starting with `192.168`

So if your router is using `192.168.1.*` then use

```
Require ip 192.168.1
```

to mean any ip on that subnet from `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.1.255`

> This answer may also help with [connecting from your phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016713/wampserver-access-server-from-mobile-phone/43018881#43018881)

Comment: Read the answer that I linked to in the yellow bit, thats how I do it

Comment: i took a little closer look at that post, but it didn't have an effect. i updated my code above. the phone's been connected, not connected... do i need to update the hosts file? thanks.

Comment: No the HOSTS file only effects the PC running WAMPServer