# Can access WAMP on mobile phone but layout is destroyed

Tags: html, css, wordpress, apache, wampserver

I am new to WAMP Server Configurations and it seems that I managed to setup my server to run on other devices by using the [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) that allows user to create a terminal for their website.

I tried visiting the URL that ngrok gave me. The layout shows properly in a desktop. BUT upon accessing it in my android phone, the layout is not showing and it is just plain HTML.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this one?

Comment: May be just because of your resources file like css, JavaScript, and images are using localhost instead of IP of your wamp server machine..

Comment: @Sudarsh i tried accessing the site using the local ip which is 192.168.x.x/mysite but still same issue.

Comment: Could you please check once if your resources (css,js,images) are accessible from the ip e.g: 192.168.x.x/mystie/css/style.css. if not, then need to correct path file in your database.

Comment: Simpler way to get [phones to access your WAMPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016713/wampserver-access-server-from-mobile-phone/43018881#43018881)