# wamp server 3.2.2 named vhost in LAN

Tags: port, wampserver, vhosts

I want a project hosted on 192.168.10.18/WAMP to be access from all pcs in LAN using a domain name
it is hosted on port 82
I can access using `www.project1.ae:82`
but if I put just `www.adcspos.ae` it is showing me the IIS bcz port 80 is used by IIS.
I can not move it to port it, I want to access it without mentioning port on client side while on server it should be hosted other than port 80.

1- 192.168.10.18/v-hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
ServerName www.project1.ae
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/project1"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/project1">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    # Require local
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2- 192.168.10.18/httpd.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:82
Listen [::0]:82
```

3- firewall port 82 allowed

4- Client-PC host file

```
192.168.10.18 www.project1.ae
```

Can I mention port here in client host or it should be handled at server.

Comment: If you use a non-standard port number you have to add that to the url in the browser

Comment: is it impossible,how shared servers host multiple sites, do they use something other than ports?

Comment: Yes, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018881/2310830) its based on allowing access from a phoen but would work just as well for lan access based on a port number