# WampServer HTTPS Port 443 give forbidden 403

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

i'm trying to make access to a PHP application using wampserver with HTTPS( :443 , .cert and .key are good ) , but after changing every thing following many topic still getting the 403 forbidden message, on HTTP ( :80 ) work just fin no problem on that.

here is my httpd-ssl.conf file :

```html
Listen 0.0.0.0:443
Listen [::0]:443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLSessionTickets   on
SSLCompression      off

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "D:/wamp64//myapp"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server.key"

#SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  10

#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>

<Directory "D:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

<Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/">
   #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
<Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/myapp/">
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


CustomLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

> > httpd.conf

```html
ServerSignature On
ServerTokens Full
Define APACHE24 Apache2.4
Define VERSION_APACHE 2.4.41
Define INSTALL_DIR d:/wamp64
Define SRVROOT ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
Define APACHE_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
Define SRVROOT ${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/apache/apache${VERSION_APACHE}
ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
PHPIniDir "${APACHE_DIR}/bin"
LoadModule php7_module "${INSTALL_DIR}/bin/php/php7.3.12/php7apache2_4.dll"
<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin wampserver@wampserver.invalid
ServerName localhost:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
HostnameLookups Off
DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Multiviews
    AllowOverride all
    
    Require local
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/apache_error.log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
        <IfModule logio_module>
    
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    
    CustomLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/access.log" common
    
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin/"
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule cgid_module>
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    
    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3
    
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 "<h2>Access denied 403</h2>"
ErrorDocument 404 "<h2>404 Page not found</h2>"
ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>500 Server too busy</h2>"

EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none

Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
Include "${INSTALL_DIR}/alias/*.conf"
```

thank you.

Comment: ?? `DocumentRoot "D:/wamp64//myapp"` 2 slashes? Why??

Comment: This `<Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/">` does not need playing with in the `httpd-vhost.conf`

Comment: i removed the <Directory "D:/wamp64/www/"> and the double slashes , but still get the 403

Comment: [Read this](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

Comment: Give your site a name like `mysite` not localhost

Comment: is it possible to use an IP address instead of a name ?

Comment: Yes, but why, what benefit would that be unless you are trying to us this site from another PC and dont have a local DNS

Comment: that's the point, it's to give local users to get access using the IP address ( waiting for a DNS from the IT team )

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018881/2310830)

Comment: i made the changes following the answer giving , still get the 403 error,  is my httpd-ssl.conf correct ?

Comment: should i reinstall the wampserver and try from the beginning again ?

Comment: Did you change anything other than httpd-ssl.conf?

Comment: > uncommunicating this line on httpd.config :

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so

> adding ( throw the answer giving ) in virtualhost :

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 192.168.156.20
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/myapp"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/myapp/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require  all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: So no you only have to work out what is wrong in httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: ok i will check again and give you feedback

Answer (score 0):

after multiple tests and changing DLLs and reinstalling WampServer, i switch to Xampp , match easier and faster to integrate SSL certificate.

thanks a lot to @RiggsFolly for the support.